# Java - Arithmetic Calculations

Tags: java, math

I have the following code snippet:

```
public class YourClassNameHere {
public static void main(String[] args) {
double x = 3 / 2 * 3;
System.out.printf("%.1f", x);
   }
}
```

I do know that **3.0** will be printed. **However, why isn't it 4.5?**

I thank you for your time and clarifications in advance.

Comment: You have to up vote the answer if it is helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation is `double x = 3 / 2 * 3` and `x` variable is store double data type but `3` and  `2` and `3` is store in integer format...

first you need to convert this number in double then you get right output

example:

```
public class YourClassNameHere {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     double a = 3;
     double b = 2;
     double c = 3;
     double x = a / b * c;
     System.out.printf("%.1f", x);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you have to use proper parenthesis to minimize error `double x = (3/2)*3`

`3\2` gives an integer value i.e `1` and to make it double you have to do `(3\2.0)` it gives double value i.e. `1.5` then `1.5 * 3 = 4.5`

Comment: Hi Rishabh, thank you for your answer. However, the question I am asking relates to how the calculcations were done to print 3.0 at the end. I thought it was 4.5 as well.

Comment: It depends on operand priorities  and associativity

Comment: The problem is nothing to do with operand priorities or associativity.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Ints which will return whole numbers.  To get the desired result simply add an "f" suffix to denote that the numbers are floating point:

`double x = 3f / 2f * 3f;`

Answer (score 0):

Just got it, it is because 3/2 = 1, in which then 1*3 becomes 3. Thank you all for the replies!